# Simple.Data Error Selecting More Than 100 Rows

Tags: sql-server, simple.data

I'm playing around with using Simple.Data for my next project, and ran across something that seems like a bug.

If I try to use the All or FindAll function for a table and the result set is more than about 100 rows (sometimes I can get 101 or 102, but I have never gotten 103), I get an Object Reference error.

My first thought is that there may be some setting that would allow me to up this limit, but I've read through all the documentation I can find and haven't seen anything like that.

I am using SQL Server.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,
according to Mark Rendle it should be fixed in the latest build:

[Result set larger than 100 rows causes error in DataReaderEnumerator](https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data/issues/143)

I think that this problem wasn't there before.

Comment: Thanks!  I looked through the bugs yesterday, but not this morning, so I didn't see that one.